# Create custom shape in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-custompainter

I'm working on a Flutter project and I need to create a custom shape that looks like the one shown below:
[image]

I've attempted to use [fluttershapemaker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/#/), but I couldn't quite achieve the exact shape I need.

I've heard about the CustomPainter widget in Flutter, but I'm not familiar with it. Can someone provide guidance on how to create this specific shape using CustomPainter or suggest alternative approaches to achieve it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: use decoration in container and position widget .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but we can't use a decoration container because the top left corner needs to have a slight outward curve. You can refer to @jmatth 's solution for the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw that with a [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html):

```dart
class CustomShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  const CustomShapePainter({
    required this.topRadius,
    required this.bottomRadius,
    required this.color,
  });

  final double topRadius;
  final double bottomRadius;
  final Color color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = color;
    final path = Path()
      // Top side
      ..lineTo(size.width - topRadius, 0)
      // Top-right corner
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width, topRadius),
        radius: Radius.circular(topRadius),
      )
      // Right side
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - bottomRadius)
      // Bottom-right corner
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - bottomRadius, size.height),
        radius: Radius.circular(bottomRadius),
      )
      // Bottom side
      ..lineTo(bottomRadius + topRadius, size.height)
      // Bottom-left corner
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(topRadius, size.height - bottomRadius),
        radius: Radius.circular(bottomRadius),
      )
      // Left side
      ..lineTo(topRadius, topRadius)
      // Top-right inverted corner
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset.zero,
        radius: Radius.circular(topRadius),
        clockwise: false,
      );

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomShapePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.topRadius != topRadius ||
        oldDelegate.bottomRadius != bottomRadius ||
        oldDelegate.color != color;
  }
}
```

[Working example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1f89b3e14c38e5c1f1469b8982b5a7da).

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly and gave the expected output. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by simply using a `Container` and set the border radius from decoration. Kindly adjust the values for the Radius based on your requirements.

```dart
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 200,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black87,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  top: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottom: Radius.circular(25),
                )
              ),
              child: const Text(
                'FEATURED',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: The original requirement was for a slight outward curve on the top left corner, and the answer you gave does not match that. Nevertheless, I'm grateful for your response.